# Why is "this" necessary when define arguments?

Tags: javascript, this

```
function Person(firstName, lastName, age)
{
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.age = age;
}

var family = {};
family.mother = new Person("Susan", "Doyle", 32);
…
```

Do we have to use "this" here? and why?

```
function …
{
     firstName = firstName;
     lastName = lastName;
     age = age;
  }
```

I wonder if this question is too simple …

Comment: `firstName = firstName;` is basically a No-Op. assigns your local variable to itself.

Comment: JavaScript isn't *that* magical; `this` is the only thing that references the newly created object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in javascript the this word is a reference to the object of invocation.

So if we have a global function

```
function () {console.log(this);} // Window
```

We get the global object or window.

if we have a deeper function in an object

```
var obj = {f: function (){console.log(this);}};
obj.f(); // Object {f: function} we get the object that wraps the function.
```

This rule is broken if we use the apply invocation pattern

```
obj.f.apply(window); // window is now bound to this.
```

In your example if you were to just call

```
Person(); // in global scope
```

you would effectively be assigning

```
window.firstName = // ...
window.lastName = // ...
window.age = //...
```

**Because the this keyword is bound to the window object when called from global scope**

You basically created a Constructor that should be called with the new operator. The new operator wraps your function with one that creates an object and calls your function using the apply method with the object as the this parameter.

```
var bob = Person("bob"); // bob is undefined but you changed the window object

var sue = new Person("sue"); // sue is an object like you expect.
```

Examine your code

```
var family = {}; // make an object
family.mother = new Person("Susan", "Doyle", 32);
```

because you used new before you function executes js makes a new object for you and uses the apply pattern to that object. This is what happens under the hood

```
family.mother = {};
Person.apply(family.mother, ["Susan", "Doyle", 32]);
```

Comment: @xxkkk sure thing. if this helped your understanding can I get an upvote too?

Comment: It requires 15 reputation ,i 'm new here,sorry , i will vote up later…

Answer (score 0):

Here `this` is required to referring the current object's value.

If you don't use the `this` keyword the local variables get shadowed down by function parameter.

In your `Person()` function scope -  the function parameter get higher priority than the local variable. That means inside your `Person()` function the by default the `firstName` is considered as the function parameter even though there is some field by the same name. In this case to reference the field the `this` keyword is used.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way to define an object constructor. you can get reference [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_definition.asp)

1. The **this** Keyword
   In JavaScript, the thing called **this**, is the object that "owns" the JavaScript code.
2. The value of **this**, when used in a function, is the object that "owns" the function.
3. The value of **this**, when used in an object, is the object itself.
4. The **this** keyword in an object constructor does not have a value. It is only a substitute for the new object.
5. The value of **this** will become the new object when the constructor is used to create an object.

**Note** that **this** is not a variable. It is a keyword. You cannot change the value of **this**.